# Using JQuery.Steps with StratusForms on SharePoint 2013 Online

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am trying to build a form where a user will go from one step to the other and at the same time use the functionality of StratusForms. I tried to use jquery.Steps for this but SharePoint will just display the whole page - I am not getting any error message and all the required libraries have been included.

Could someone please suggest any pointers?

Regards,
George